# How to change email content in tank_auth?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, tankauth

I use Tank_auth for authentication in my codeigniter project.
when i create a new account or reset my password. standard emails were sent. how do i change the content/language for these emails?

I searched my whole application folder but could not find anything related.

Hope someone can point me to the right place.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tank auth stores HTML files for emails in `application/views/email/`. Check that location. You will guess the purpose of each file by it's name.